# Can I import a Javascript library file (in this case sigma.js) in a self executing function?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, sigma.js, self-executing-function

I use a technology that unfortunately relies on the old [Prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) framework (check out that modern looking website!). I'd like to include a sigma.js graph on the page, but just put the script tag on to import sigma gives this error:

```
TypeError: sigma.utils.matrices is undefined sigma.min.js:2
```

I don't know the exact cause of this, although I [have asked](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/380), but I think it's conflicting with Prototype.js.

Is it possible to put all my sigma.js code in a self executing function, along with the sigma.js import, so it doesn't conflict?

Comment: have you updated to the latest version of PrototypeJS (April 2014) ? that might solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the Prototype import at all, as it's generated by a tool. I promise if I tell you all the details you'll shake your head and agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
(function(sigma){
 //your usage of sigma     sigma.classes.graph....
})(sigma);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I also import the thing in a noconflict way?

Comment: I guess you could use a local var name that is unique `(function($s){$s.classes.graph....})(sigma)`, but re declaring sigma in the local scope should have already done this

Comment: I think I'm being confusing. When I say import, I literally mean the script tag that tells the browser to get the javascript file. Currently if I just put that - and nothing else - as a normal script tag in my browser, I get the error message in the question.

Comment: that does seem strange, I wander if you might be able to re-create the problem on jsfiddle ?